# Running older version of Node in terminal on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I have had the latest version of node(v12) by running

```
brew install node
```

but I want to have the previous version(v10)
I have uninstalled node and installed the previous version by running

```
brew install node@10
```

now when I run node --version I get nothing. How can I link the node keyword to what now is node@10 on mac?

Comment: I would recommend using 'n' - https://github.com/tj/n
It's easy to install and use and lets you switch instantly between multiple node versions.

Comment: You could look into something like nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like linking the node keyword to node@10.

The @10 represents the current version of the environment installed.

**Check if you have installed Xcode. Node.js and some of its components will rely on Xcode's Command Line Tools package.**

**You can follow the blog for a correct installation:** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-and-create-a-local-development-environment-on-macos